# What does the Greek word “σκωληξ” in Mark 9:44 really mean?

Tags: greek, mark

In today’s Greek language “οκουληκι” means worm, and the plural form, worms, is “σκουλήκια”. In the Biblical Greek original text we read in Mark 9:44 the word “σκωληξ”. Google Translate does not have a translation for this word, but Strongs app translates it “worm”. Did the Strongs app get it right?

If the last letter “ξ” is removed Google Translate recognises it and translates it “worm”. What does that little Greek letter “ξ” do to the word. Does it make the word into plural, or is the word still singular after the add on? Or does it change the word into something slightly different?

Comment: See modern Greek versions on youversion Bible.com. On duckduckgo search you find wordsense and wiktionary results. Such ques are better answered on Quora than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern Greek is not ancient Greek.  The word for "worm" in ancient Koine Greek is simply σκώληξ (nominative masculine singular).  Modern Greek has simplified the language in many respects and this is one of them.

Note that Mark 9:44 and 46 are disputed as they only appear in the Byzantine text; NA28 and UBS5 omit these verse.  This means that on the basis of the UBS5 text, σκώληξ is a hapex legomenon (occurs only once in the NT) in Mark 9:48.

Comment: V44 and 46 are identical scribal additional from 48.

Comment: What is the difference between “σκωληξ” and “σκωλη”, please?

Comment: @Constantthin - σκωληξ is ancient Greek word and σκωλη is the modern Greek word.

Comment: “οκουληκι“ and  “σκωλη” both mean “worm” according to Google Translate. How do you explain the different spelling?

Comment: @Constantthin - that bis a question for someone who knows more about modern Greek.  However, according my modern Greek dictionary, all three are allowable in modern Greek.

Comment: Ok. Thx for sharing what you know. It has been a great help.

Comment: When you say all three, which is the third one you are referring to? Is it “σκουλήκια“  that means worms (plural)?

Comment: @Constantthin - οκουληκι, σκωλη and σκώληξ.

Comment: I see even that last word you find in your dictionary.  Google Translate does not recognize it. Interesting.

Comment: @Constantthin I just made an account because I randomly ran into this and I can answer. Not a linguistics professional but I'm a Greek dude, so I can give you context. Σκουλήκι is the word we use every day in modern Greek. σκώληξ is a words that is the  predecessors of the modern word. However, since modern Greek still has a LOT of things coming from ancient Greek, these words have followed and we still use them in random places. For example, when you go to a fishing supplies store you could see the word σκώληκες (worms) when they advertise bait interchangeably.

Comment: @Constantthin Also, I may be wrong but I don't think the word 'Σκώλη' exists.